# Difference between earlier, recently, and lately

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, time-words

I am having difficulty in distinguishing between these time words.

For example,

> I ate my meal *earlier/recently/lately.*

When to use earlier, recently, and lately? What if I've done an action a few minutes ago? What will be the appropriate word?

Comment: A related question: "*[difference between 'recently' and 'lately'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32571/difference-between-recently-and-lately)*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I ate my meal **earlier**.

means you ate your meal before that time, in the same day.

> I ate my meal **recently**.

means you ate your meal before that time but not long ago.
But I would not say it is a normal usage in this example.

> I ate my meal **lately**.

means on some past occasion(s). But the past time frame is not specific.
Again I would not say it is a normal usage in this example. But some additional context would make it more natural. For example:

> I have been going to work **lately**, even though I didn't want to.

As for what happened "a few minutes ago", I would say:

> I **just** ate my meal.